# Linux Logical Volume Manager

Tags: linux, mount

I can see that a single Logical volume can be mounted on two different file systems -- now can someone explain to me the pros and cons of this? Why doesn't Linux throw up error when this happens?

Ex:

```
/dev/mapper/vgEP0-lvol12
9.9G 9.2G 243M 98% /LSMW


/dev/mapper/vgEP0-lvol12
9.9G 9.2G 243M 98% /oracle/EP0/oraflash
```

Comment: Perhaps turn it around -- why _would_ you expect a problem with multiply-mounted filesystems? Files can have hardlinks, files and directories can be bind-mounted into multiple locations; why are multiple direct mounts so odd that you want them to be an error? :)

Comment: It just happened in one of our company servers as it's a design error - someone did that by mistake, So just trying to figure out whether any errors would come up in the near future :) may be some one could share their experience

Comment: @GergelySzilagyi sure will do that

Comment: I'm extrapolating here -- perhaps the design error was considering a path to be a unique file identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux a device can be mounted multiple times.

From mount(2) man page

```
Since Linux 2.4 a single file system can be visible at multiple  mount
points, and multiple mounts can be stacked on the same mount point.
```

Comment: thanks mate :)but by doing it this way - what are pros and cons ? any idea ?

Comment: no real cons beyond having the same file be referenced in 2 different locations (so for example, if you had path name based security, you could have an issue).

Comment: When extending file systems ? will there be a problem ?

Comment: There will be a issue when mounted at multiple points. For ex: In a production environment where one file system is used by database and the other by a normal user - what if some one deletes some files on the same. it could be a real disaster

Comment: dont know, your issues strike me as issues that could exist in any place, even with a single file system mount.